# Unity XCode project GooglePlayService build issue

Tags: xcode, unity-game-engine, google-play-games

I already added UIKit.framework,

but I will get build error in XCode below,

Anyone know how to fix that?

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_UIPresentationController", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in gpg(GPGToastView.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_UIUserNotificationSettings", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in gpg(GPGManager.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_UIMutableUserNotificationCategory", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in gpg(GPGManager.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_UIMutableUserNotificationAction", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in gpg(GPGManager.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

XCode version:5.1.1

Answer (score 0):

You want to check the Other Linker Flags and make sure you added -ObjC.

When you build the XCode project out from Unity, the Google Play Games plugin shows a dialog with instructions on how to build the project in XCode.
These instructions are noted in the documentation too at https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity#building-for-ios.